# ESP8266 Wifi Module - prints “ready” but not responding to AT commands

Tags: wifi, at-commands, esp8266

Just received my first ESP8266 wifi module with some excitement. However I've been unable to fully communicate with it. I have connected the module to my computer via a usb to serial cable and I'm power the module via a separate power supply (3.3v).

After powering the module up I receive the following information (via PuTTY or and Arduino serial monitor window):

```
[Vendor:www.ai-thinker.com Version:0.9.2.4]

ready
```

I have tried sending various AT commands e.g.

```
AT+RST
```

But I get no response. Using ctrl+m and ctrl+j in putty didn't help either.

Please see my youtube video if its helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvasOuHuWDc

Comment: Check your TX line (the one that is transmitting the data from the computer/micro to the module)

Comment: What kind of USB-to-serial, not an USB-to_RS232 I hope? Do you get the echo of the characters you type?

Comment: is there anything else on the serial line that could be loading it down? Are you sure you are doing your AT commands properly?

Comment: my Xbee for example needed me to send "+++" first, and then it goes into AT command mode. From then on, I use "ATID\n" for example to ask it what it's PAN ID is. Make sure you include (or not) appropriate new-line characters if needed, my Xbee module expects new line characters after each AT command. There is also a guard time between each AT command (1 second for me). Check that your wifi module has not got all these annoying AT command things, something like that could be the issue

Comment: Are you using `Both NL & CR` setting in Arduino serial monitor?

Comment: I have the same problem using an FTDI adapter. ESP say ready but i don't get any response from module. I did set the "Both NL & CR" and still no answer.
The ESP8266 is powered from external source (battery).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. The solution was modify the line ending option at the bottom of the Arduino serial console to send both CR and LF. Still not got PuTTY configured but have something to test now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently started "playing" with this module, and there are a few things to keep in mind:

- the module base baud rate is 115200, don´t waste your time on 9600
- it requires CR+LF to accept commands
- read the documentations (http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=225)
- experiment with more than one tool, like Arduino IDE and Esplorer
- also check the resources here: http://www.electrodragon.com/w/Category:ESP8266

And of course, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/cabo/ce6358406f8175041813

You can enable/disable crlf in screen comfortably.